# Regex in java to match a string begining with html followed by something

Tags: java, regex

Can someone help me out with a regex to match a string which starts with the following eg:
The string can begin with any html tag eg: 
    < span > or < p >  etc so basically I want a regex to check if a string begins with any opening html tag <> and then followed by [apple videoID=

Eg:

```
<span>[apple videoID=
```

Here's what I've tried :

```
static String pattern =  "^<[^>]+>[apple videoID=";
static Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(pattern);
```

What is wrong in the above?

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2846923)

Comment: You have to implement a grammar of some sort to detect matching characters in a string. Regular expressions are called regular for a reason, it means they can only parse languages that can be described by finite state machines (automata) and matching characters would require infinite states.

Comment: what do you mean? It's a pattern that I'm compiling. Pattern.compile()

Comment: Oh, nevermind. If you know the amount of brackets you want then it's possible.

Comment: yeah, It should start with <.*><apple videoId=

Comment: It seems to work for me, but it can be cleaner: [`^<[^>]+><apple videoID=`](http://regex101.com/r/gB7tU2)

Comment: `[A-za-z]` This range seems to be wrong. It should be `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: you need to escape `[` in `[apple videoID=`, as such : `\[apple videoID=`

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the following line.

```
static String pattern = "^<[^>]+>[apple videoID=";
```

This string is not a valid regular expression because you have an unclosed `[` right before the word `apple`, hence the "Unclosed character class" `PatternSyntaxException`.  You either meant to type

```
static String pattern = "^<[^>]+><apple videoID=";
```

assuming that `apple` is an html tag, or

```
static String pattern = "^<[^>]+>\\[apple videoID=";
```

if you really did want the `[` in front of apple.  This is because `[` is a special character in regular expressions and must be escaped with a `\` which is a special character in Java strings and must be escaped with a `\`.  Therefore `\\[`.

Answer (score 0):

simple as this:

```
<[.]+><apple videoID=[.]*
```

Comment: I think it should be <.*><apple videoID=   as tag can contain anything, not just chars

Comment: @Sam I've updated the post. Please check. That's not working for me. It says unclosed characeter class

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` helps  to fetch the pattern either in upper case or lower case.

Tested and Executed.

```
    package sireesh.yarlagadda;

    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class Pattern {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String text="<span><apple videoID=";

            String patternString = "<[a-zA-Z]*>\\<apple videoID=";

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

            System.out.println("lookingAt = " + matcher.lookingAt());
            System.out.println("matches   = " + matcher.matches());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Oh I guess you got me wrong. I don't want to consider any html between the apple tag. I want to match the string which begins with 1 html tag. It could be span or p etc .. . 1 html tag followed by "<apple videoID=" thats what I want

Comment: All the second asterisk does (`>*`) is match 0+ `>`s.  [As you can see](http://regex101.com/r/rH9kH7), that will cause unintended consequences.

Comment: Changed the solution to fit the requirement. Removed asterisk. Case sensitive is added.  @Sam

Comment: what's the point of `[a-zA-Z]` if you are using `CASE_INSENSITIVE` ?

Comment: You are right. It even works with [a-z] . Just to play safe. @njzk2

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern :

```
"^<[A-Za-z]+>\\[apple videoID=$"
```

This pattern will match [apple videoID=

Hope this will help you..!

Comment: not a chance. the `^` and `$` means this must be a complete line.